# how to cover the Parameterized method in test class

Tags: apex, unit-test

for eg private static test(color c)

Comment: Can you add code to cover and test class which you have done so far.

Answer (score 1):

One problem is that your method is declared as `private` which means other classes can't access it. This includes Unit Tests. There's a few ways around this. You could:

- Declare the method as `public`
- Call instead a `public` method that calls the `private` one
- Use the `@TestVisible` annotation

As [@Mahmood](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/9807/mahmood) mentioned in the comments:

> It is accepting a workbook object. You need to first create a workbook object and then call your method and pass it on.

So, to cover this class you could do something as simple as creating a new `Workbook` object and calling it (working under the assumption you've changed `private` to `public` or another workaround):

```
@isTest static void test_method_one() {
    Workbook wrkbk = new Workbook(
        // Assign fields values here...
    );

    INSERT wrkbk;

    myClassThatContainsTheMethod.processActionPlan(wrkbk);
}
```

That would start covering code, but you're going to have to create multiple instances of `Workbook` objects that match each case if your long `if/then` statements.

For instance, your first `if/then` statement is:

```
if(sheet.sheet.contains('Action Plan')) {
```

Thus you need to ensure that your `sheet.sheet` contains the `String` "*Action Plan*". If you don't do this, you'll find that a very small percentage of the method is covered because if as in this case it doesn't match "*Action Plan*" it'll skip everything inside and continue on. In this instance, to the end of the method.

I strongly advise looking over some [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/apex_testing/units/apex_testing_intro) modules on Unit Testing. In a nutshell, think of it as programatically executing your classes and methods and asserting that the value returned does what you expect.

For instance, if you have a class like below:

```
public class Example {
    public static Integer addNumbers(Integer x, Integer y) {
        return x + y;
    }
}
```

Your unit test might look something like this:

```
@isTest static void test_method_one() {
    Integer a = 10, b = 17; // Create two numbers to add together
    Integer result = Example.AddNumbers(a, b); // Call the class and the method and assign it to another variable

    System.assertEquals(27, result); // We know 10 + 17 = 27, so that's what we expect. If `result` returns something different, we know there's a problem and the test will fail
}
```

Comment: i have tried this  Workbook wrkbk = new Workbook();
                          insert wrkbk;
                       CRSImport.processActionPlan(wrkbk);
getting error- Invalid type: Workbook

Comment: @user42459 `Workbook` isn't a standard object. If it's custom you'd need to append `__c` or if it's formed as part of a wrapper class you'd need to build that in the Unit Test.

Comment: WorkBook is not wrapper class. public class WorkBook {
        public List<Sheet> sheets { get; set; }
    }

Answer (score 0):

Private methods are not visible in Test Classes. Hence use @TestVisible annotation so that the method is accessible for running tests only. Use as shown below.

```
@TestVisible private static void processActionPlan(Workbook workbook) {

your code 

}
```

Refer this link [TestVisible Annotation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_testvisible.htm) for further details.